# Android Broadcast receiver receives null action in onReceive

Tags: android

I am having problem on some devices (ie. Alcatel Pop D5), that my Broadcast reciver gets `onResume()` method invoked but `intent.getAction() == null`.

Here is the command for setting up a reciver:

```
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    mReceiver = new WakeStateReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Anyone else got this issue? Did anyone of those solved it? :)

There is no mention of WakeStateReceiver anywhere else in the project (inlcuding manifest).
Have tested this with about 20 different devices and none of them had this issue (until Pop D5).

Thanks in advance,
ivan

Comment: what if you try to declare the broadcast receiver in the appmanifest xml ?

Comment: I have tried that, but that made all sort of problems on other devices

Comment: Or maybe create a background service?

Comment: I tought of it too, but it seamed like a huge under-optimized behaviour